# How to execute multiple rows of statements returned as a result of another select statement

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb, export

I have a Select statement query using CONCAT that yields a set of other SELECT statements. How can I execute those iteratively?

Here's my first query

```
SELECT CONCAT( 'SELECT body from knowledge where id=''', id, '''', ' INTO OUTFILE ''', '/tmp/',CAST(id AS CHAR), '.html'';') FROM knowledge ORDER BY id;
```

This results in a row of select statements:

```
 SELECT body from knowledge  where id='1' INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/1.html';                                                         |
| SELECT body from knowledge  where id='2' INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/2.html';                                                         |
| SELECT body from knowledge  where id='3' INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/3.html';                                                         |
| SELECT body from knowledge  where id='4' INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/4.html';                                                         |
| SELECT body from knowledge  where id='5' INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/5.html';                                                         |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.000 sec)
```

These set of queries returned in each row needs to be executed. How can I do this?

Comment: Use a stored procedure. You are assembling SQL statements on the fly and to execute them you need to use stored procedure logic.

Comment: You have to write a stored procedure. It can put the result in a variable, then use `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to outfile the queries in another .txt file and then use > source file.txt to run all the queries.

Comment: That will not work if server and client run on different machines, unless you copy the generated files from server to client - not really the easiest way.